# Google webmaster tool detects errors in sitemap?

Tags: sitemap, robots.txt, google-search-console

I have a sitemap that looks like this :

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:geo="http://www.google.com/geo/schemas/sitemap/1.0">

<url>

<loc>http://www.MyApp.se</loc>
<lastmod>2012-06-29</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>1.0</priority>
<url>

<loc>http://www.MyApp.se/Ad/Edit</loc>
<lastmod>2012-06-29</lastmod>
<changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<url>

<loc>http://www.MyApp.se/Site/Faq</loc>
<lastmod>2012-06-29</lastmod>
<changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<url>

<loc>http://www.MyApp.se/Site/Support</loc>
<lastmod>2012-06-29</lastmod>
<changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<url>

<loc>http://www.MyApp.se/Site/AboutMyApp</loc>
<lastmod>2012-06-29</lastmod>
<changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<url>

<loc>http://www.MyApp.se/Site/News</loc>
<lastmod>2012-06-29</lastmod>
<changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<url>

<loc>http://www.MyApp.se/Site/Cookies</loc>
<lastmod>2012-06-29</lastmod>
<changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
</url>
<url>

<loc>http://www.MyApp.se/Ad/Detail?id=283</loc>
<lastmod>2012-06-26</lastmod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<url>

<loc>http://www.MyApp.se/Ad/Detail?id=284</loc>
<lastmod>2012-06-26</lastmod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<url>

<loc>http://www.MyApp.se/Ad/Detail?id=285</loc>
<lastmod>2012-06-26</lastmod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<url>

<loc>http://www.MyApp.se/Ad/Detail?id=286</loc>
<lastmod>2012-06-26</lastmod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<url>

<loc>http://www.MyApp.se/Ad/Detail?id=294</loc>
<lastmod>2012-06-28</lastmod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
</urlset>
```

And this is my Robo.txt :

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
Sitemap: <http://www.MyApp.se/Site/Sitemap/>
```

The problem is that in Google Webmaster tool I get the following errors :

```
1
Warning
Invalid XML-tagg
This tag could not be identifyed.
**Problems :** 6
Tag: url
**Row :** 7
Tag: url
13
Tag: url
**Row :** 19

2
Warning 
Webadress blocked by robots.txt.
Sitemap contains webadresses that is blocked by robots.txt.
**Problems :** 12
Value : http://www.MySite.se
Value: http://www.MySite.se/Ad/Detail?id=283
Value: http://www.MySite.se/Ad/Detail?id=284
```

Why? I have constructed the sitemap according to guides on internet?

Comment: Google really wrote "XML-tagg" and "identifyed"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the `<url>` tags are all over the place. Everything from the opening `<loc>` tag to the closing `</priority>` tag for each website page must be enclosed within a set of `<url>` tags. See amended code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">

<url>
<loc>http://www.MyApp.se</loc>
<lastmod>2012-06-29</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>

<url>
<loc>http://www.MyApp.se/Ad/Edit</loc>
<lastmod>2012-06-29</lastmod>
<changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>

<url>
<loc>http://www.MyApp.se/Site/Faq</loc>
<lastmod>2012-06-29</lastmod>
<changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>

<url>
<loc>http://www.MyApp.se/Site/Support</loc>
<lastmod>2012-06-29</lastmod>
<changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>

<url>
<loc>http://www.MyApp.se/Site/AboutMyApp</loc>
<lastmod>2012-06-29</lastmod>
<changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>

<url>
<loc>http://www.MyApp.se/Site/News</loc>
<lastmod>2012-06-29</lastmod>
<changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>

<url>
<loc>http://www.MyApp.se/Site/Cookies</loc>
<lastmod>2012-06-29</lastmod>
<changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>

<url>
<loc>http://www.MyApp.se/Ad/Detail?id=283</loc>
<lastmod>2012-06-26</lastmod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>

<url>
<loc>http://www.MyApp.se/Ad/Detail?id=284</loc>
<lastmod>2012-06-26</lastmod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>

<url>
<loc>http://www.MyApp.se/Ad/Detail?id=285</loc>
<lastmod>2012-06-26</lastmod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>

<url>
<loc>http://www.MyApp.se/Ad/Detail?id=286</loc>
<lastmod>2012-06-26</lastmod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>

<url>
<loc>http://www.MyApp.se/Ad/Detail?id=294</loc>
<lastmod>2012-06-28</lastmod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>

</urlset>
```

Just to tidy up your `robots.txt` file, make it look as below. Make sure the `Sitemap` declaration links to the location of your `sitemap.xml` file:

```
User-agent: *
Sitemap: http://point-this-to-your-sitemap.xml
```

There's also no need for an empty `Disallow` declaration.

This is the basic structure I follow for the websites that I develop, so it should be fine!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the beginning of your file, you seems to have a problem with XML tags, you seem to have forgotten a  after the first  bloc. You have :

```
     <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:geo="http://www.google.com/geo/schemas/sitemap/1.0">

    <url>

    <loc>http://www.MyApp.se</loc>
    <lastmod>2012-06-29</lastmod>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
    <url>

    <loc>http://www.MyApp.se/Ad/Edit</loc>

[...]
```

And you should have :

```
     <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:geo="http://www.google.com/geo/schemas/sitemap/1.0">

    <url>        
    <loc>http://www.MyApp.se</loc>
    <lastmod>2012-06-29</lastmod>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
    </url>

    <url>
    <loc>http://www.MyApp.se/Ad/Edit</loc>

[...]
```

I think you have the same problem somewhere else in your code. You could try to use an XML editor to verify.